# Getting parts of a URL in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, urlparse

How can I extract the following parts using PHP function:

- The Domain
- The path without the file
- The file
- The file with Extension
- The file without Extension
- The scheme
- The port
- The query
- The fragment
- (add any other that you think would be useful)

Ex.1
  https://stackoverflow.com/users/test/login.php?q=san&u=post#top

- The Domain (stackoverflow.com)
- The path without the file (/users/test/)
- The file(login.php)
- The file Extension (.php)
- The file without Extension (login)
- The scheme(https:)
- The port(return empty string)
- The query(q=san&u=post)
- The fragment(top)

Ex: 2 stackoverflow.com/users/test/login.php?q=san&u=post#top

- The Domain (stackoverflow.com)
- The path without the file (/users/test/)
- The file(login.php)
- The file Extension (.php)
- The file without Extension (login)
- The scheme(return empty string)
- The port(return empty string)
- The query(q=san&u=post)
- The fragment(top)

Ex: 3 /users/test/login.php?q=san&u=post#top

- The path without the file (/users/test/)
- The file(login.php)
- The file Extension (.php)
- The file without Extension (login)
- The query(q=san&u=post)
- The fragment(top)
- For remaining (return empty string)

Ex: 4 /users/test/login?q=san&u=post#top

- The path without the file (/users/test/)
- The file(login)
- The file Extension (return empty string)
- The file without Extension (login)
- The query(q=san&u=post)
- The fragment(top)
- For remaining (return empty string)

Ex: 5 login?q=san&u=post#top

- The file(login)
- The file Extension (return empty string)
- The file without Extension (login)
- The query(q=san&u=post)
- The fragment(top)
- For remaining (return empty string)

Ex: 6 ?q=san&u=post

- The query(q=san&u=post)
- For remaining (return empty string)

I checked parse_url function, but doesn't return what I need. Since, I'm beginner in PHP, it was difficult for me. If you have any idea, please answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ***login**?q=san&u=post#top -> The file(**login.php**)* - Where is `.php` in the input?

Comment: What did `parse_url` not return?

Comment: ya. sougata. I have tired "parse_url" function. but its only working for Ex.1(I have mentioned above). For remaining case it's not giving proper answer.

Comment: @SanKaRan -  So what do you need that parse_url() doesn't give you? Does using parse_url() with pathinfo() give you everything?

Comment: @stribizhev. Oops. I have edited. thanks :)

Comment: File and extension don't *really* have anything to do with the URL, especially with `mod_rewrite` and everything else is covered by `parse_url()` isn't it?

Comment: for my sec case(Ex.2) it is return my domain as empty. path as stackoverflow.com/users/test/.

Comment: The problem with your second example is that it's quite possible to have a directory called *stackoverflow.com* rather than that being a domain, e.g. `http://example.com/stackoverflow.com/` would be a perfectly valid URL... there's no way you can guarantee you're parsing that correctly without the scheme... or at least a leading slash or two. `parse_url()` is, I presume, treating `stackoverflow.com` as part of the path in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP provides a [`parse_url`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

> This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing
>   any of the various components of the URL that are present.
>
> This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks
>   it up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also accepted,
>   **`parse_url()`** tries its best to parse them correctly.

---

You can see the test cases [executed here](https://eval.in/469447).

```
$urls = array(
  "https://stackoverflow.com/users/test/login.php?q=san&u=post#top",
  "/users/test/login.php?q=san&u=post#top",
  "?q=san&u=post#top",
  "login.php?q=san&u=post#top",
  "/users/test/login?q=san&u=post#top",
  "login?q=san&u=post#top"
);
foreach( $urls as $x ) {
  echo $x . "\n";
  var_dump( parse_url($x) );
}
```

Comment: *I checked parse_url function, but doesn't return what I need.*

Comment: @hipotter. thanks. but for my sec case it's not working fyn. its return as ["path"]=> string(38) "stackoverflow.com/users/test/login.php".

Comment: @SanKaRan How'll you differentiate b/w `website.info/page.php?query` and `page.php/website.info?query`? Both of them are valid as `path` but only one qualifies as actual webhost.

Comment: @hipotter. yep I agree with your point. but any other idea is there to differentiate bw these two.

Answer (score 1):

I"m using this to locate the root and webroot

```
<?php

/**
 * @brief get paths from the location where it was executed.
 */
class PathHelper {
    /**
     * @brief This function tries to determine the FileSystem root of the application. (needs to be executed in the root)
     * @return string
     */
    public static function locateRoot($file) {
        $dir = dirname($file);
        /** FIX Required for WINDOWS * */
        $dir = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '/', $dir);
        $dir = preg_replace('/\\\/', '/', $dir);
        return $dir;
    }

    /**
     * @brief This function tries to determine the WebRoot. (needs to be executed in the root)
     * @return string
     */
    public static function locateWebroot($file) {
        $docroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $dir = dirname($file);
        if ($dir == $docroot) {
            $webroot = "";
        } else {
            $webroot = substr_replace($dir, '', 0, strlen($docroot));
        }
        /** FIX Required for WINDOWS * */
        $webroot = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '/', $webroot);
        $webroot = preg_replace('/\\\/', '/', $webroot);
        return $webroot;
    }
}
```

I set this as a constant so i can use it throughout my application.

For example:

For a menu you can do something like this:

```
   // the requested url
    $requestedUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // remove the webroot from the requested url
    $requestedUrl = str_replace(WEBROOT, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    // take away the / if they still exist at the beginning
    $requestedUrl = ltrim($requestedUrl, "/");
```

Then i got this:
index.php?controller=User&action=overview

This equals to my url of one of my menu items.
You could use explode on this last url to find all the other values you want.

Edit: Its probably better to use parse_url(). I am not used to all the functions in PHP but if nothing works then this is atleast a fallback.